# error: unknown/unsupported geography heirarchy when querying data for all ZCTA5s

Tags: r, census

I'm trying to query data with the R package "censusapi."

The following code...

```
getCensus(
     name = "sf1",
     vars = c("P0010001"),
     region = "zip code tabulation area:*",
     vintage = 2010,
     key = Sys.getenv("CENSUS_KEY")
 )
```

...throws this error...
`Error: error: unknown/unsupported geography heirarchy`.

Any idea what I need to fix here so I can get 2010 population data for every ZCTA5? Replacing `"zip code tabulation area:*"` with `"county:*" works fine, by the way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Census API documentation](https://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1/geography.html). ZCTA is nested under states in the geography hierarchy. Seems a little odd, since normally ZCTAs are supposed to be independent of states or counties. The more "pure" ZCTA has a level number 860; the one nested under states has level 871. I have no idea how much they may differ.

So for ZCTAs, you need to give it a state in `regionin`, like:

```
censusapi::getCensus("sf1", 
    vars = c("P0010001"), 
    region = "zip code tabulation area:*", 
    vintage = 2010, 
    key = Sys.getenv("CENSUS_KEY"), 
    regionin = "state:09")
```

If you needed zips for every state, you might be stuck `apply`ing or `map`ping over all states' FIPS codes and plugging into `regionin`.

Comment: This works. But something confuses me. Why don't I need `regionin` when I query the 2016 5-year ACS. For instance, try running `getCensus(
    name = "acs/acs5",
    vars = c('B25058_001E'),
    region = "zip code tabulation area:*",
    vintage = 2016,
    key = Sys.getenv("CENSUS_KEY")
)`. All ZCTA5 rows show up. But if you add the `regionin` argument, the code returns the error from my question...

Comment: Because it's available in the [API](https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs5/geography.html) for the acs5, but not for the sf1. Don't know the Census's rhyme or reason for that